# mixed results for stationarity tests and structural breaks

Tags: time-series, stationarity, test-for-trend

Following situation: I want to forecast a time series of the number of trucks on the motorway in some country. Here how the regular week looks like:
[image: regular week]

I have data for 4 years and divide the huge time series in 672 part time series… so we have now time series for example like a measurement of the number of vehicles each Monday at 11 o’clock:
[image]

Then I test the time series for if it is season-stationary or trend-stationary with R-function  nsdiffs() and ndiffs() respectively. Both tests (OCSB and CH) for season-stationary deliver the same result (ts is season stationary). With SLT-decomposition I adjust the time series for seasonality and test it for trend-stationary with adf-, kpss- and pp-test (R-function ndiffs()). Here I have mixed results: adf and pp shows stationary but kpss not! I figured out that kpss is very sensitive to structural breaks and there are some of them (R-function breakpoints()):

[image]

Thinking logically the trend should be deterministic because the population of trucks is growing but still the kpss-test causes headache. Are there any possibilities to include structural breaks into kpss-test? Or how should I deal with mixed results?

here the data:

```
20605
20601
20082
19972
19796
20438
19102
18613
18726
18268
18871
19367
19983
20234
20448
20955
20562
20792
21150
20859
20223
21416
20942
21423
21251
20713
20842
19050
19222
19203
19199
19879
20348
20009
20539
20609
20437
20749
19760
21252
21521
21780
21361
21565
22200
19679
21280
21433
21356
21377
21814
21611
20203
21786
21269
21237
21283
20745
20020
19551
19845
18818
20174
20693
21265
21311
21894
21670
21697
22163
21801
22227
21291
21898
22212
22239
22175
22510
21825
20503
20591
21325
19726
20647
20913
20623
19395
20669
19897
21394
21758
21914
22221
22167
22521
22948
22258
22149
21827
22709
22985
22593
21024
22684
21853
21785
21553
21560
21342
20963
20280
20038
21349
21169
21906
22384
22745
23381
23879
21895
23948
23982
23963
24000
23863
24078
23730
24430
23798
23961
23675
23075
23046
22931
21937
22143
21997
22099
22598
24531
22346
22626
23210
21782
23608
24197
22297
24080
24440
24461
23191
24572
24442
23143
24556
24090
23678
24088
24377
23823
24045
23529
23070
22395
21855
22124
22474
23123
23627
26134
28123
24117
25423
24317
24146
24465
24865
24939
23668
24604
25143
25002
24836
24585
23283
23376
20938
23820
24169
23805
23552
24480
24600
24286
23098
24873
25072
25462
25528
25221
25813
22726
25669
25366
24827
25536
25407
25444
22891
25720
25296
24859
24419
24400
24044
24312
22913
22499
22566
22899
24297
24478
25040
25317
25884
```

Comment: You can apply the KPSS test recursively for overlapping subsamples. In this way you could check if rejection of the null arises when the subsample enters a period containing a break. For example, taking subsamples of length $50$, you can do something like: `id <- embed(seq_along(x), 50); for(i in seq(nrow(id))) print(tseries::kpss.test(x[rev(id[i,])],null="Trend"))`.